# asp .net Application performance

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance-testing

I have an asp .net 4.0 application. I have an mdf file in my app_data folder that i store some data. There is a "User" table with 15 fields and an "Answers" table with about 30 fields. In most of the scenarios in my website, the user retrieves some data from "User" table and writes some data to "Answers" table.

I want to test the performance of my application when about 10000 users uses the system.What will happen if 10000 users login and use the system at the same time and how will the performance is affected ? What is the best practice to test my system performance of asp .net pages in general?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: There's no way to answer this question with the information provided. We don't know your set up.

Comment: what is the best practice do measure database performance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It reads like performance testing/engineering is not your core discipline.   I would recommend hiring someone to either run this effort or assist you with it.   Performance testing is a specialized development practice with specific requirement sets, tool expertise and analytical methods.   It takes quite a while to become effective in the discipline even in the best case conditions.

In short, you begin with your load profile.   You progress to definitions of the business process in your load profile.   You then select a tool that can exercise the interfaces appropriately.   You will need to set a defined initial condition for your testing efforts.   You will need to set specific, objective measures to determine system performance related to your requirements.  Here's a document which can provide some insight as a benchmark on the level of effort often required, http://www.tpc.org/tpcc/spec/tpcc_current.pdf

Something which disturbs me greatly is your use case of "at the same time," which is a practical impossibility for systems where the user agent is not synchronized to a clock tick.   Users can be close, concurrent within a defined window, but true simultaneity is exceedingly rare.

Comment: The term "at the same time" was used a bit incorrect i agree and performance testing is not my dicscipline. what i ment by "at the same time" is the case where people do some request on the page in a close interval. Thanks for your help.